# Customize window.open

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, window.open

Hi I am using Electron and I want to change the `window.open` function so that, by default, it opens popups hidden/invisible, minimized and some other things.

I found this code:
`window.open(url, windowName, 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none', '');`

But I want to make it so that all calls of `window.open` have these `windowFeatures` by default, but still accepts the original `url` and `windowName` parameters.

Comment: `function myCustomWindowOpen(url, windowName) { window.open(url, windowName, ...); }`

Comment: But I want to redefine window.open so that by simply calling window.open, it will default with those custom options.

Comment: You can override `window.open` behaviour by registering listener to [webcontent's `new-window` event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-new-window) in main process. I think that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, webContents} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow() // you may create more
  // general callback
  const onWindowOpen = (event, url, frameName) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      show: false,
      frame: false,
      resizable: false,
      title: frameName
    })
    win.loadURL(url)
    win.webContents.on('new-window', onWindowOpen)
    event.newGuest = win
  }
  // wait every dom-ready
  Promise.all(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().map(br => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      br.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => { resolve() })
    })
  })).then(() => {
    // register every new-window callback
    webContents.getAllWebContents().forEach(wc => {
      wc.on('new-window', onWindowOpen)
    })
  })
  // load URL(s) for BrowserWindow(s)
  win.loadURL(path.resolve(__dirname, 'your.html'))
})
```

Here we add listeners to `new-window` event for every initially created BrowserWindows **and** for every BrowserWindow created by `window.open` calls. Newly created BrowserWindow is frameless, invisible and not resizable as it seems to be your goal altogether.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This seems like exactly what I want, but for some reason it's not working. I am calling `window.open` from a webview inside a renderer. Does this make a difference? Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: @TMack Yes, I could reproduce that. If we wait every BrowserWindow to be ready, then `getAllWebContents` will contain `<webview>` processes and the code applies to them. I've edited the answer according to that! _you can implement "wait every dom-ready" part more elegant for sure, I just wanted to keep it short_

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working but it still doesn't seem to respond correctly :( Let me debug a little more so I can give you more helpful feedback